# Cant start second Android project in one solution

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I have two android projects at one solution. The first one deploying on device and works fine, the second one not starting saying "The project XXX needs to be deployed before it can be started. Verify the project is selected to be deployed in the Solution Configuration Manager." But configuration is fine, both projects marked as build and deploy.
When i create new solution containing only one project (first or second, doesn't matter) they works fine. The problem only when both projects at one solution at the same time. What to do?

Comment: Can you share a demo? I test it in my VS 2019, I can running secound projects at same solution normally.